# Determine Excel VBA code range for multiple cells

Tags: vba, excel, range, cells

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("$C$17:$C$80")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Select Case Target
    Case ""
        Target = "Priority 1"
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    Case "Priority 1"
        Target = "Priority 2"
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    Case "Priority 2"
        Target = "Priority 3"
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 45
    Case Else
        Target = ""
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 15
    End Select
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

I am having issues with my range. I need to expand my range to only specific cells. How would I go about doing this? The cells I need selected are,

> C17,C21,C25,C29,C33,C42,C46,C50,C54,C58,C67,C71,C75,C83,C87,C91,C100,M17,M21,M25,M29,M33,M42,M46,M55,M59,M69,M73,M82,M86,W17,W21,W25,W29,AG17,AG21,AG25,AG34,AG38,AG42,AG51,AG55,AG59,AG68,AG72,AG81,AG85,AG89,AG98,AG102,AG106,AG110,AG114,AQ17,AQ21,AQ30,AQ34,AQ43,AQ47,AQ51,AQ60,AQ64,BA17,BA21,BA25,BA29,BA33,BA37,BA46,BA50,BA54,BA58,BA62,BA71,BA75,BA79,BA89,BA93".

The above cells need priority selections with color change and the cells below need only a color change for a status update. How do I go about doing this as well?

> C19,C23,C27,C31,C35,C44,C48,C52,C56,C60,C69,C73,C77,C85,C89,C93,C102,M19,M23,M27,M31,M35,M44,M48,M57,M61,M71,M75,M84,M88,W19,W23,W27,W31,AG19,AG23,AG27,AG36,AG40,AG44,AG53,AG57,AG61,AG70,AG74,AG83,AG87,AG91,AG100,AG104,AG108,AG112,AG116,AQ19,AQ23,AQ32,AQ36,AQ45,AQ49,AQ53,AQ62,AQ66,BA19,BA23,BA27,BA31,BA35,BA39,BA48,BA52,BA56,BA60,BA64,BA73,BA77,BA81,BA91,BA95"

Comment: You could also make these named ranges and then refer to them that way.

Comment: Named range approach is very sensible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String constants cannot be longer than 255 characters in VBA. You've got to split the statement up:

```
Dim HotArea As Range

Set HotArea = Range("C17,C21,C25,C29,C33,C42,C46,C50,C54,C58,C67,C71,C75,C83,C87,C91,C100,M17")
Set HotArea = Union(HotArea, Range("M21,M25,M29,M33,M42,M46,M55,M59,M69,M73,M82,M86,W17,W21,W25,W29,AG17,AG21,AG25,AG34"))
Set HotArea = Union(HotArea, Range("AG38,AG42,AG51,AG55,AG59,AG68,AG72,AG81,AG85,AG89,AG98,AG102,AG106,AG110,AG114,AQ17"))
Set HotArea = Union(HotArea, Range("AQ21,AQ30,AQ34,AQ43,AQ47,AQ51,AQ60,AQ64,BA17,BA21,BA25,BA29,BA33,BA37,BA46,BA50,BA54"))
Set HotArea = Union(HotArea, Range("BA58,BA62,BA71,BA75,BA79,BA89,BA93"))

If Not Intersect(Target, HotArea) is Nothing Then
...
```

or alternatively in one statement

```
    Set HotArea = Union(Range("C17,C21,C25,C29,C33,C42,C46,C50,C54,C58,C67,C71,C75,C83,C87,C91,C100,M17"), _
            Range("M21,M25,M29,M33,M42,M46,M55,M59,M69,M73,M82,M86,W17,W21,W25,W29,AG17,AG21,AG25,AG34"), _
            Range("AG38,AG42,AG51,AG55,AG59,AG68,AG72,AG81,AG85,AG89,AG98,AG102,AG106,AG110,AG114,AQ17"), _
            Range("AQ21,AQ30,AQ34,AQ43,AQ47,AQ51,AQ60,AQ64,BA17,BA21,BA25,BA29,BA33,BA37,BA46,BA50,BA54"), _
            Range("BA58,BA62,BA71,BA75,BA79,BA89,BA93"))
```

as `Union()` takes an arbitrary number of arguments.

Comment: "String constants cannot be longer than 255 characters in VBA" That's not true. The issue is that `Range()` will not accept a string longer than 255 characters.

Comment: Thank you, That worked perfectly. I appreciate your help. @user1016274

Answer (score 3):

You would put what you typed directly in the `range` statement.  As stated because of vba's limit of 255 characters in the range statement you would need to use the `union` statement

```
Union(Range("C17,C21,C25,C29,C33,C42,C46,C50,C54,C58,C67,C71,C75,C83,C87,C91,C100,M17,M21,M25"), _
            Range("M29,M33,M42,M46,M55,M59,M69,M73,M82,M86,W17,W21,W25,W29,AG17,AG21,AG25,AG34,AG38,AG42,AG51,AG55"), _
            Range("AG59,AG68,AG72,AG81,AG85,AG89,AG98,AG102,AG106,AG110,AG114,AQ17,AQ21,AQ30,AQ34,AQ43,AQ47,AQ51,AQ60"), _
            Range("AQ64,BA17,BA21,BA25,BA29,BA33,BA37,BA46,BA50,BA54,BA58,BA62,BA71,BA75,BA79,BA89,BA93"))
```

You would then use a `else if` to do the second

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
If Not Intersect(Target, Union(Range("C17,C21,C25,C29,C33,C42,C46,C50,C54,C58,C67,C71,C75,C83,C87,C91,C100,M17,M21,M25"), _
            Range("M29,M33,M42,M46,M55,M59,M69,M73,M82,M86,W17,W21,W25,W29,AG17,AG21,AG25,AG34,AG38,AG42,AG51,AG55"), _
            Range("AG59,AG68,AG72,AG81,AG85,AG89,AG98,AG102,AG106,AG110,AG114,AQ17,AQ21,AQ30,AQ34,AQ43,AQ47,AQ51,AQ60"), _
            Range("AQ64,BA17,BA21,BA25,BA29,BA33,BA37,BA46,BA50,BA54,BA58,BA62,BA71,BA75,BA79,BA89,BA93"))) Is Nothing Then
    Select Case Target.Value
        Case ""
            Target = "Priority 1"
            Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        Case "Priority 1"
            Target = "Priority 2"
            Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        Case "Priority 2"
            Target = "Priority 3"
            Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 45
        Case Else
            Target = ""
            Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 15
    End Select
ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Union(Range("Your Second Group"))) Is Nothing Then
   'do your second stuff here
End If
Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Also, as @matthewD stated in the comments, you could name both ranges and refer to the name instead.  This has a huge advantage if you will refer to these two specific ranges multiple times.  If only the once then it is the same.

As this has been changed to reflect input from others I have changed it to a community wiki.

Comment: This is not working. It keeps highlighting the original If Intersect statement and telling me there is a syntax error. @ScottCraner

Comment: @C.Cons I am stepping into a meeting that will last most this morning.  I will work on it when I get back, sorry.

Comment: I could be talking out of my backside - but I think there's a character limit on what you can supply for a string argument in a `Range()` method - you might have to break it down and use `Union()` to append the ranges.

Comment: @C.Cons I have changed to reflect the information provided from others, and changed it to a community wiki.